# module is found in cmd but not working in idle python

Tags: python, module, python-idle

is  there something wrong with this? no right?

> sys.path

```
['', 'C:\\Users\\rande\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib\\idlelib',
 'C:\\Users\\rande\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\rande\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\rande\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\rande\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\rande\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks normal.  But when you run from Command Prompt, the initial '', which stands for the current directory, may be different.  You should show the import code that fails.  Is it for a module you wrote or one that you downloaded?  What directory is it in?